# Create Calendar powershell CSOM

Tags: powershell, calendar, client-object-model, sharepoint-calendar

How would I go about creating a calendar in powershell using CSOM.
I have created a custom list before, using this :

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'

Function Invoke-LoadMethod() {

param(

$ClientObject = $(throw "Please provide an Client Object instance on which to invoke the generic method")

) 

$ctx = $ClientObject.Context

$load = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext].GetMethod("Load") 

$type = $ClientObject.GetType()

$clientObjectLoad = $load.MakeGenericMethod($type) 

$clientObjectLoad.Invoke($ctx,@($ClientObject,$null))

}

function CreateList()

{

 param(

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$url,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][System.Net.NetworkCredential]$credentials

 )

 $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)

  $ctx.Credentials = $credentials

  $web = $ctx.Web 

  Invoke-LoadMethod -ClientObject $web

  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

  $ListInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListCreationInformation
  $ListInfo.Title = $ListTitle
  $ListInfo.TemplateType = "100"
  $myList = $web.Lists.Add($ListInfo)
  $myList.Description = $ListTitle
  $myList.Update()
  $Fields=$myList.Fields
  $ctx.Load($Fields)
  $ctx.ExecuteQuery() 

  $myList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml("<Field Type='URL' DisplayName='PrivacyStatementUrls' Required='TRUE' />",$true,     [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AddFieldOptions]::AddFieldToDefaultView)
  $myList.Update()

  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

  $myList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml("<Field Type='Boolean' DisplayName='IsActive' />",$true,[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AddFieldOptions]::AddFieldToDefaultView)
  $myList.Update()
  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()



  $field = $myList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml("<Field Type='Number' DisplayName='SortOrder'/>",$true,[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AddFieldOptions]::AddFieldToDefaultView)
  $myList.Update()
  $field.Indexed = $true;
  $field.EnforceUniqueValues = $true;
  $field.Update();
  $ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Would it be similar to this maybe just changing the template type?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter

```
$ListInfo.TemplateType = "100"
```

needs to be

```
$ListInfo.TemplateType = "106"
```

to create a calendar list.

For all template types see the documentation here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd958106%28v=office.12%29.aspx